# .....The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform

I am getting this issue while trying to get the project details from GCP using the following API using local ISE. I use the below code to get token and hit the GCP.

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
$Uri = "https://IpAddress/api/token/gcp/" 
$jwtToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body {}
$token = $jwtToken.access_token   
$getUrl = "https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v3/projects/XXXXXXXXX"
$headers = @{'Content-Type'='application/json';'Authorization'='Bearer $token'}
$getTags = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $getUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers
```

First 4 lines of the script is used to get the token, which is used to get the project details.
when I tried to get the token without this     `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}` got similar error.

```
The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

To sort out this, I have added the below line of code to my script

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
```

Is the above line disturbing the whole script? or is there anything that I am missing. Can any one help me to sort this error.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**[Update]**

Your problem is with this line of code:

```
$Uri = "https://IpAddress/api/token/gcp/"
```

Only self-signed certificates have an IP address for the CN (common name). That is why the certificate validation is failing.

Change **IpAddress** to the domain name. If your service does not have a domain name that matches the SSL certificate, then you must disable certificate validation or write a custom validator that knows the hash value of your self-signed certificate.

**[End Update]**

By setting **ServerCertificateValidationCallback** to return true, you are preventing certificate validation (ignoring certificate errors).

**Do not disable certificate validation.**

You have an underlying problem, either with root certificates or the TLS protocol version.

Replace

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
```

With

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Got similar error this time         "Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel".